# Should __init__() call the parent class's __init__()?

Tags: python, oop, superclass

I'm used that in Objective-C I've got this construct:

```
- (void)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // init class
    }
    return self;
}
```

Should Python also call the parent class's implementation for `__init__`?

```
class NewClass(SomeOtherClass):
    def __init__(self):
        SomeOtherClass.__init__(self)
        # init class
```

Is this also true/false for `__new__()` and `__del__()`?

**Edit:** There's a very similar question: [Inheritance and Overriding `__init__` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753640/inheritance-and-overriding-init-in-python)

Comment: you've changed your code significantly. I can understand that original `object` was a typo. But now you don't even have `super` title of your question refers to.

Comment: I just thought that super is used as a name for the parent class. I didn't think anyone would think of the function. I'm sorry for any misunderstandings.

Comment: A why not automatic super call question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782827/why-arent-pythons-superclass-init-methods-automatically-invoked

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In Python, calling the super-class' `__init__` is optional. If you call it, it is then also optional whether to use the `super` identifier, or whether to explicitly name the super class:

```
object.__init__(self)
```

In case of object, calling the super method is not strictly necessary, since the super method is empty. Same for `__del__`.

On the other hand, for `__new__`, you should indeed call the super method, and use its return as the newly-created object - unless you explicitly want to return something different.

Comment: So there's no convention to just call super's implementation?

Comment: In old-style classes, you could only call the super __init__ if the super class actually had an __init__ defined (which it often doesn't). Therefore, people typically think about calling super method, rather than doing it out of principle.

Comment: If the syntax in python was as simple as `[super init]`, it would be more common. Just a speculative thought; the super construct in Python 2.x is a bit awkward to me.

Comment: Here seems to be an interesting (and possibly contradicting) example: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/39811-consequences-not-calling-object-__init__

Comment: "optional" in that you don't have to call it, but if you don't call it, it's not going to get called automatically.

Comment: you should _always_ call super(), rather than explicitly name. Python supports multiple inheritance and super() will initialize all superclasses.

Answer (score 163):

If you need something from super's `__init__` to be done in addition to what is being done in the current class's `__init__,` you must call it yourself, since that will not happen automatically.  But if you don't need anything from super's `__init__,` no need to call it.  Example:

```
>>> class C(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = 1


>>> class D(C):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__() # in Python 2 use super(D, self).__init__()
            self.a = 1


>>> class E(C):
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 1


>>> d = D()
>>> d.a
1
>>> d.b  # This works because of the call to super's init
1
>>> e = E()
>>> e.a
1
>>> e.b  # This is going to fail since nothing in E initializes b...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#70>", line 1, in <module>
    e.b  # This is going to fail since nothing in E initializes b...
AttributeError: 'E' object has no attribute 'b'
```

`__del__` is the same way, (but be wary of relying on `__del__` for finalization - consider doing it via the with statement instead).

I rarely use `__new__.`  I do all the initialization in `__init__.`

Comment: The definition of class D(C) must be corrected like that ``super(D,self).__init__()``

Comment: super().__init__() only works in Python 3. In Python 2 you need super(D, self).__init__()

Comment: "If you need something from super's __init__..." - This is a very problematic statement because it is not a case of whether the you/the subclass needs "something", but whether the base class needs something in order to be a valid base class instance and work correctly. As implementer of the derived class, base class internals are things that you cannot/should not know, and even if you do because you wrote both or internals are documented, design of the base may change in the future and break because of a poorly written derived class. So always ensure that the base class is initialised fully.

Comment: In fact, you do NOT need to call super().__init__() for it to do its job. If you don't define an __init__ method super().__init__() will be called automatically.  For example, in your code above:  class E(C);  e=E();  e.b  will actually return 1   as long as you don't write an __init__ method

Comment: @PabloAlvarez would you have a source for that, please?

Comment: @Onilol This is implied by the way inheritance works, and the way __init__() is defined here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects. You can see an example of it in the python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Answer (score 134):

In Anon's answer:
 *"If you need something from super's `__init__` to be done in addition to what is being done in the current class's `__init__` , you must call it yourself, since that will not happen automatically"*

It's incredible: he is wording exactly the contrary of the principle of inheritance.

It is not that *"something from super's `__init__`  (...)  will not happen automatically"* , it is that it WOULD happen automatically, but it doesn't happen because the base-class' `__init__` is overriden by the definition of the derived-clas `__init__`

So then, WHY defining a derived_class' `__init__` , since it overrides what is aimed at when someone resorts to inheritance ??

It's because one needs to define something that is NOT done in the base-class' `__init__` , and the only possibility to obtain that is to put its execution in a derived-class' `__init__` function.
In other words, **one needs something in base-class' `__init__` in addition** to what would be automatically done in the base-classe' `__init__` if this latter wasn't overriden.
 NOT the contrary.

Then, the problem is that the desired instructions present in the base-class' `__init__` are no more activated at the moment of instantiation. In order to offset this inactivation, something special is required: calling explicitly the base-class' `__init__` , in order to **KEEP** , NOT TO ADD, the initialization performed by the base-class' `__init__` .
That's exactly what is said in the official doc:

> An overriding method in a derived class may in fact want to **extend
>   rather than simply replace the base class method** of the same name.
>   There is a simple way to call the base class method directly: just
>   call BaseClassName.methodname(self, arguments).
>   http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

That's all the story:

- when the aim is to KEEP the initialization performed by the base-class, that is pure inheritance, nothing special is needed, one must just avoid to define an `__init__` function in the derived class
- when the aim is to REPLACE the initialization performed by the base-class, `__init__` must be defined in the derived-class
- when the aim is to ADD processes to the initialization performed by the base-class, a derived-class' `__init__`  must be defined , comprising an explicit call to the base-class `__init__`

What I feel astonishing in the post of Anon is not only that he expresses the contrary of the inheritance theory, but that there have been 5 guys passing by that upvoted without turning a hair, and moreover there have been nobody to react in 2 years in a thread whose interesting subject must be read relatively often.

Comment: I was sure that this post was going to be upvoted. I'm afraid that I won't have a lot of explanation about the reasons why. It's easier to downvote than to analyze a text that appears incomprehensible. I had a long time trying to understand the Anon's post before I finally realized that it was speciously written and not very much authoritative. Maybe it can be interpreted as approximately right for someone who knows about the inheritance; but I find it confusioning when read by someone having unsteady notions about inheritance, a subject not as clear as rock water in general

Comment: "I was sure that this post was going to be upvoted..."  Main issue is that you're a little late to the party, and most people may not read beyond the first few answers.  Great explanation by the way +1

Comment: You missed the significant words "in addition" in the sentence you quoted from Aaron.   Aaron's statement is completely correct, and matches what you end up saying.

Comment: This is the first explanation that made python's design choice make sense.

Answer (score 24):

**Edit**: (after the code change)
There is no way for us to tell you whether you need or not to call your parent's `__init__` (or any other function). Inheritance obviously would work without such call. It all depends on the logic of your code: for example, if all your `__init__` is done in parent class, you can just skip child-class `__init__` altogether.

consider the following example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val


>>> class B(A):
    pass

>>> class C(A):
    def __init__(self, val):
        A.__init__(self, val)
        self.a += val


>>> A(4).a
4
>>> B(5).a
5
>>> C(6).a
12
```

Comment: I removed the super call from my example, is I wanted to know if one should call the parent class's implementation of __init__ or not.

Comment: you might want to edit the title then. but my answer still stands.

Answer (score 6):

There's no hard and fast rule. The documentation for a class should indicate whether subclasses should call the superclass method. Sometimes you want to completely replace superclass behaviour, and at other times augment it - i.e. call your own code before and/or after a superclass call.

**Update:** The same basic logic applies to any method call. Constructors sometimes need special consideration (as they often set up state which determines behaviour) and destructors because they parallel constructors (e.g. in the allocation of resources, e.g. database connections). But the same might apply, say, to the `render()` method of a widget.

**Further update:** What's the OPP? Do you mean OOP? No - a subclass often needs to know *something* about the design of the superclass. Not the internal implementation details - but the basic contract that the superclass has with its clients (using classes). This does not violate OOP principles in any way. That's why `protected` is a valid concept in OOP in general (though not, of course, in Python).

Comment: You said that sometimes one would want to call own code before the superclass call. To do this, one needs knowledge of the parent class's implementation, which would violate the OPP.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, you should call it. If your superclass is `object`, you should not, but in other cases I think it is exceptional not to call it. As already answered by others, it is very convenient if your class doesn't even have to override `__init__` itself, for example when it has no (additional) internal state to initialize.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should always call base class `__init__` explicitly as a good coding practice. Forgetting to do this can cause subtle issues or run time errors. This is true even if `__init__` doesn't take any parameters. This is unlike other languages where compiler would implicitly call base class constructor for you. Python doesn't do that!

The main reason for always calling base class `_init__` is that base class may typically create member variable and initialize them to defaults. So if you don't call base class init, none of that code would be executed and you would end up with base class that has no member variables.

**Example**:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self):
    print('base init')

class Derived1(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    print('derived1 init')

class Derived2(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Derived2, self).__init__()
    print('derived2 init')

print('Creating Derived1...')
d1 = Derived1()
print('Creating Derived2...')
d2 = Derived2()
```

This prints..

```
Creating Derived1...
derived1 init
Creating Derived2...
base init
derived2 init
```

[Run this code](https://repl.it/@sytelus/derivedinit).