# Python: Inherit the superclass __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, init

I have a base class with a lot of `__init__` arguments:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        self._a=a+b
        self._b=b if b else a
        ...
```

All the inheriting classes should run `__init__` method of the base class.

I can write a `__init__()` method in each of the inheriting classes that would call the superclass `__init__`, but that would be a serious code duplication:

```
class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        super(A, self).__init__(a, b, c, d, e, f, ...)

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        super(A, self).__init__(a, b, c, d, e, f, ...)

class C(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        super(A, self).__init__(a, b, c, d, e, f, ...)

...
```

What's the most Pythonic way to automatically call the superclass `__init__`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
super(SubClass, self).__init__(...)
```

Consider using *args and **kw if it helps solving your variable nightmare.

Comment: It helps, but is there a way to completely avoid explicitly calling the superclass __init__?

Comment: @Adam Matan No, there isn't. See here why: [Why aren't Python's superclass __init__ methods automatically invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782827/why-arent-pythons-superclass-init-methods-automatically-invoked)

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus correct, but it still requires the annoying code duplication for every base class.

Comment: Are there any difference from BaseClass.__init__(self,*args,*kwargs) and super(BaseClass, self).__init__(*args,*kwargs) ?

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld yes. If you called `BaseClass.__init__` inside of `BaseClass(): __init__:` you would get infinite recursion. `super` calls the parent class.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Sorry, I have a very stupid question. In Python 3, how can I use the ellipsis to feed the __init__()? I kept getting errors. When you guys used "...", did you really mean ellipsis in the code or it was just meant to save typing?

Comment: what if I want to pass new params in class A?

Answer (score 45):

You have to write it explicitly, but on the other hand, if you have lots of args, you should probably use *args for positional args and **kwargs for keyword args.

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # SubClass initialization code
```

Another technique you could use is to minimize the code in **init** and then at the end of **init** function, call another custom function. Then in the subclass, you just need to override the custom function

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialization code
        self._a = kwargs.get('a')
        ...
        # custom code for subclass to override
        self.load()

    def load():
        pass

class SubClass(BaseClass)
    def load():
        # SubClass initialization code
        ...
```

Comment: This is a technique I've used, in some cases going so far as to provide `preinit()` and `postinit()` hooks. The return value from `preinit()` can be saved in a local variable in `__init__` and passed to `postinit()`, which is convenient sometimes.

Comment: @kindall I want to write a superclass that does some modest, uniform member checking of subclass instances (viz., that needed member variables exist and have sane contents), as part of their  `__init__` process. I think this sort of `postinit()` hook should work perfectly.

Comment: improvement: kwargs.get('a', defaultvaluehere) instead of kwargs.get('a')

Comment: I like this method, but for me it makes more sense to pass **kwargs to the loader as that way the positional args are reserved for the base class arguments that will exist in every implementation and keyword arguments can be used to pass in arguments specific to any given implementation.

Answer (score 21):

If the derived classes don't implement anything beyond what the base class `__init__()` already does, just omit the derived classes `__init__()` methods - the base class `__init__()` is then called automatically.

If, OTOH, your derived classes add some extra work in their `__init__()`, and you don't want them to explicitly call their base class `__init__()`, you can do this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        new = object.__new__(cls)
        new._a=a+b
        new._b=b if b else a
        ...
        return new

class A(BaseClass):
    ''' no __init__() at all here '''

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        ''' do stuff with init params specific to B objects '''
```

Since `__new__()` is always called automatically, no further work is required in the derived classes.

Comment: Fine method, usefull to know. +1. - By the way, as in the question, the code needs to be corrected: _class BaseClass(object)_ instead of _def BaseClass(object)_

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps a clearer implementation for your case is using **kwargs **combined with new added arguments** in your derived class as in:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, d, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.d = d
```

By this method you avoid the code duplication but preserve the implicit addition of arguments in your derived class.

Comment: all solution should looks like this one.

Comment: Running `Child(1, 2, 3, 4) ` I get `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given`. I suspect this should be `*args` instead of `**kwargs`

Comment: by using args, you might mix between your arguments when calling to your child classes. This is why it is better practice in such situation to use **kw and named arguments

Answer (score 14):

Unless you are doing something useful in the subclass `__init__()` methods, you don't have to override it.

```
def BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...):
        self._a=a+b
        self._b=b if b else a
        ...

def A(BaseClass):
    def some_other_method(self):
        pass

def B(BaseClass):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2.6 and lower version to inherit init from base class, there is no super function, You can inherit below way:

```
class NewClass():
     def __init__():
         BaseClass.__init__(self, *args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Pythonic implementation.  Assuming you want all attributes passed in, you can use the code below.  (Can also keep/remove specific kwargs keys if you want a subset).

```
def A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

base = BaseClass(...)
new = A( **base.__dict__ )
```