# Python: how to create initializer of a derived class

Tags: python, constructor

I have a class `order_order`:

```
class order_order(osv.osv):

    _inherit = "sale.order"

    _columns = {
        'order_completed_date' : fields.char('Order Completed Date'),
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535832/python-inherit-the-superclass-init) SO post I wrote the following initializer:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(order_order, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.order_completed_date = order_completed_date
    .
    .
    .
```

I am trying to create an object as:

```
order_order.__new__(order_completed_date=order_completed_date, ...)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order_completed_date'
```

**EDIT:** Getting the same error with:

```
order_order(order_completed_date=order_completed_date, ...)
```

**EDIT2:**
Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nish/repos/stage/openerp/web/addons/web/http.py", line 292, in dispatch
    r = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/home/nish/repos/stage/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/spree_api.py", line 118, in some_html
    order_order(order_completed_date=order_completed_date, order_id=order_id, product_id=product_id, product_name=product_name, size=size, product_cost_cp=product_cost_cp, product_cost_sp=product_cost_sp, product_cost_mrp=product_cost_mrp, product_creation_date=product_creation_date, product_taxon=product_taxon, user_email=user_email, user_name=user_name, user_address=user_address, user_city=user_city, city_zip_code=city_zip_code, user_state=user_state, user_country=user_country)
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_address'
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I correct the error?

Answer (score 2):

`__new__` is the type’s constructor, and you usually don’t want to use it like that *ever*. The normal way to create an object, that also includes calling its initializator is this:

```
order_order(order_completed_date=order_completed_date, ...)
```

So, just call the type; and the parameters of that call will be passed to the initializator.

Comment: Do I need to make changes in the initializer of base class?

Comment: Can you show the full error message? The *same* error is unlikely (since you are no longer calling `__new__` explicitely); but it’s possible that passing the keyword arguments to the base type. You should probably not pass the keyword arguments to the base’s `__init__`.

Comment: Well, in the file `spree_api.py`, on line 119, you are still calling `order_order.__new__(…)` instead of just `order_order(…)`.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the old traceback. PLease can you have a look again. Even without __new__, I am getting the same error

Comment: Also tried `super(order_order, self).__init__()`. But same

Comment: @nish Could you [join chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) so that we can discuss this in more detail?