# Python subclass does not display parent class attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am using python 2.6

```
class Father(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_rich = 'yes'
        self.single  = 'yes'

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.has_job = 'yes'

son = Son()
print dir(son)  --> Does not display Father class attributes is_rich & single?
```

Why?

Comment: Since when did being "single" become a heritable trait?  ;-)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger His wife died and now he is single. Just wanted to use a funny example.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- [Amoebas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexual_reproduction) seem to manage it.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't call `Father.__init__`.  You need to do so explicitly or use `super`<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Father.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.has_job = 'yes'
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>[super considered Super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>[super considered harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)</sup>

Comment: I think it's sort of funny that to create the instance the parameters are in somewhat-reverse order (eg. `son = Son("employed","wealthy","bachelor"`) when using `*args`, `**kwargs`: `class Son(Father): def __init__(self, has_job, *args, **kwargs)`. Compared to creating the instance by repeating the keywords in the child's init: `class Son(Father): def __init__(self, is_rich, is_single, has_job)`. (eg. (`son = Son("wealthy","bachelor","employed"`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call base class's `__init__`, as python only invokes the first `__init__` method found in the class hierarchy the `__init__` in `Father` is never invoked. You can do that using `super` or using `Father.__init__` as shown in @mgilson's answer.

```
class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Son, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.has_job = 'yes'
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> s = Son()
>>> s.is_rich
'yes'
>>> s.single
'yes'
>>> s.has_job
'yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you didn't have your child chain the initialization up towards its parent.

Perhaps reading this will help: [Why aren't Python's superclass __init__ methods automatically invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782827/why-arent-pythons-superclass-init-methods-automatically-invoked)

Comment: For what it's worth, by the way, I'd recommend that you normally start your __init__ suite by calling each of your parent constructors, left to right (same order as you'd be reading them, given that the language uses English reserved and keywords.

If you have need to perform initialization in some other order, or to skip initialization of any parent classes then you should DEFINITELY document your justification for that.