# the meaning of the instruction

Tags: python, sql, sqlmap

I found this code in sqlmap project https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/master/lib/core/datatype.py
.

I don't understand the meaning of calling the constructor `AttribDict.__init__(self)`

```
class InjectionDict(AttribDict):
    def __init__(self):
        AttribDict.__init__(self)

        self.place = None
        self.parameter = None
        self.ptype = None
        self.prefix = None
        self.suffix = None
        self.clause = None

        # data is a dict with various stype, each which is a dict with
        # all the information specific for that stype
        self.data = AttribDict()

        # conf is a dict which stores current snapshot of important
        # options used during detection
        self.conf = AttribDict()

        self.dbms = None
        self.dbms_version = None
        self.os = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InjectionDict` class is a subclass, the base class it inherets from is `AttribDict`. That's what this syntax means

```
class InjectionDict(AttribDict):
```

Then in `InjectDict`'s `__init__` method, they are calling the base class's `__init__` method first, before doing the rest of the subclass specific `__init__` work.

```
AttribDict.__init__(self)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782827/why-arent-pythons-superclass-init-methods-automatically-invoked) for a more thorough explanation of what this behavior is used for.

Comment: Yes, almost exactly like that.

Comment: Not only like super in java, but python new style classes) has this syntax too: so instead of the line you asked about you can write:

    ```super(InjectionDict, self).__init__(self)```