# pyFPDF .add_page() function breaking when instantiating from classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pyfpdf

The `add_page()` function errors whenever I try to get any user input in `__init__()` or a `classmethod`. It works fine when I don't have any methods to get user input, so I think it's somehow interfering.

> AttributeError: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'state'. Did you mean: 'rotate'?

**Error**

```
Name: ttt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/106404228/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 63, in <module>
    pdf = PDF.get_name()
  File "/workspaces/106404228/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 44, in get_name
    return cls(name)
  File "/workspaces/106404228/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.add_page(self, format='a4')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 813, in add_page
    if self.state == DocumentState.CLOSED:
AttributeError: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'state'. Did you mean: 'rotate'?
```

**Code**

```py
from fpdf import FPDF


class PDF(FPDF):

    def __init__(self, name):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("no name")

        self.name = name
        self.add_page(self, format='a4')

    # header
    def header(self):
        self.image("shirtificate.png")
        self.ln(20)


    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        name = input("Name: ")
        return cls(name)


    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name


    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("no name")
        self._name = name

pdf = PDF.get_name()
pdf.set_font("helvetica", "B", 16)
pdf.output("shirtificate.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the user input, but it's because you are calling `.add_page` when the `FPDF` object is not yet properly instantiated. You can replace the user input with a hardcoded `name` and you would still get the same error. The classmethod is just making the problem more visible.

You can see the sequence of what's happening from the Traceback:

```
  File "/workspaces/106404228/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 44, in get_name
    return cls(name)
  File "/workspaces/106404228/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.add_page(self, format='a4')
```

The `return cls(name)` code will instantiate the `FDPF` object, which then calls *your* `__init__`, which then calls `.add_page`. But [`.add_page`](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_page/index.html) is an instance method of the `FDPF` class. It's expected to be called *after* the object has been instantiated. In your code, since the `__init__` of the parent `FPDF` class wasn't called, then your object would be missing a `.state` and all the other attributes of a `FPDF` object, which leads to the error:

> 'PDF' object has no attribute 'state'

You can check the [`__init__` method](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/cb3340806c140b6e63eb4ce9d6230be84fba456e/fpdf/fpdf.py) of the `FPDF` class to see what it does. If you are creating a custom subclass, you typically call the parent's `__init__` as part of your subclass `__init__`. (see [Why aren't superclass `__init__` methods automatically invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3782827/2745495)).

The fix is to reorganize your code to something like this:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

class PDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("no name")

        # Call the parent FPDF init
        super().__init__()

        # Add your custom code after
        self.name = name
 
    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        name = input("Name: ")
        # Create the object
        obj = cls(name)
        # Call FPDF object instance methods
        # after it is created to customize
        obj.add_page(format="A4")
        return obj

    ...

pdf = PDF.get_name()
pdf.set_font("helvetica", "B", 16)
pdf.output("shirtificate.pdf")
```

Here, the main changes are:

1. Calling `super().__init__()` to [call the parent's `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2399307/2745495)
2. Calling `.add_page` after instantiating an object

Another recommended change would be renaming that classmethod since it does more than just "getting the name". It should be called something like `create_from_name` or `create_with_prompted_name`.

Comment: I read your post and learned a lot more about how classes work, since I am pretty new to them. Will definitely go back to this page when I get stuck on a similar error :)