# Python functools.wraps equivalent for classes

Tags: python, decorator

When defining a decorator using a class, how do I automatically transfer over`__name__`, `__module__` and `__doc__`?  Normally, I would use the @wraps decorator from functools.  Here's what I did instead for a class (this is not entirely my code):

```
class memoized:
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            return self.cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            value = self.func(*args)
            self.cache[args] = value
            return value
        except TypeError:
            # uncacheable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
            # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
            return self.func(*args)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.func.__repr__()

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

    __doc__ = property(lambda self:self.func.__doc__)
    __module__ = property(lambda self:self.func.__module__)
    __name__ = property(lambda self:self.func.__name__)
```

Is there a standard decorator to automate the creation of name module and doc?  Also, to automate the get method (I assume that's for creating bound methods?)  Are there any missing methods?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Everyone seems to have missed the obvious solution. Using [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper):

```
>>> import functools
>>> class memoized(object):
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)  ## TA-DA! ##
    def __call__(self, *args):
        pass  # Not needed for this demo.

>>> @memoized
def fibonacci(n):
    """fibonacci docstring"""
    pass  # Not needed for this demo.

>>> fibonacci
<__main__.memoized object at 0x0156DE30>
>>> fibonacci.__name__
'fibonacci'
>>> fibonacci.__doc__
'fibonacci docstring'
```

Comment: The `__name__` and `__doc__` are set on the _instance_, but not the class, which is what is always used by `help(instance)`. To fix, a class-based decorator implementation cannot be used, and instead the decorator must be implemented as a function. For details see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25973438/1988505.

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer was suddenly marked down yesterday.  No one asked about getting help() to work.  In 3.5, inspect.signature() and inspect.from_callable() got a new follow_wrapped option; perhaps help() should do the same?

Comment: Fortunately ipython's `fibonacci?` does show both the __doc__ from the wrapper, and the memoized class so you get both

Comment: This does not produce picklable class decorators

Comment: Update: Starting from Python 3.9, help() now shows the wrapped function's docstring, though it still lacks the argument list

Answer (score 29):

I'm not aware of such things in stdlib, but we can create our own if we need to.

Something like this can work :

```
from functools import WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS


def class_wraps(cls):
    """Update a wrapper class `cls` to look like the wrapped."""

    class Wrapper(cls):
        """New wrapper that will extend the wrapper `cls` to make it look like `wrapped`.

        wrapped: Original function or class that is beign decorated.
        assigned: A list of attribute to assign to the the wrapper, by default they are:
             ['__doc__', '__name__', '__module__', '__annotations__'].

        """

        def __init__(self, wrapped, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS):
            self.__wrapped = wrapped
            for attr in assigned:
                setattr(self, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))

            super().__init__(wrapped)

        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.__wrapped)

    return Wrapper
```

Usage:

```
@class_wraps
class memoized:
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            return self.cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            value = self.func(*args)
            self.cache[args] = value
            return value
        except TypeError:
            # uncacheable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
            # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
            return self.func(*args)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)


@memoized
def fibonacci(n):
    """fibonacci docstring"""
    if n in (0, 1):
       return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)


print(fibonacci)
print("__doc__: ", fibonacci.__doc__)
print("__name__: ", fibonacci.__name__)
```

Output:

```
<function fibonacci at 0x14627c0>
__doc__:  fibonacci docstring
__name__:  fibonacci
```

**EDIT:**

And if you are wondering why this wasn't included in the stdlib is because you can
wrap your class decorator in a function decorator and use `functools.wraps` like this:

```
def wrapper(f):

    memoize = memoized(f)

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def helper(*args, **kws):
        return memoize(*args, **kws)

    return helper


@wrapper
def fibonacci(n):
    """fibonacci docstring"""
    if n <= 1:
       return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Comment: Thanks mouad.  Do you know what the purpose of the `__get__` method is?

Comment: Oh, I see: it makes the decorator work with methods?  It probably should be in class_wraps then?

Comment: @Neil: Yes For more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469956/python-decorator-self-is-mixed-up/5470017#5470017 , IMO i don't think so because it will violate one of the principles that i believe in for function or class which is **unique responsibility** , which in the case of `class_wraps` will be to __Update a wrapper class to look like the wrapped.__ no less not more :)

Comment: @mouad: Thanks a lot.  I have a couple more questions (for you or anyone else) if you don't mind:  1. Isn't it true that we will want to override `__get__` for all "callable class" decorators?  2.  Why do we use `functools.partial` instead of returning a bound method with `types.MethodType(self.__call__, obj)`?

Comment: @Neil: 1. Yes if you want to be able to decorate also methods (not just functions) as you already said , and i strongly believe that it's a good practice to implement also the `_get__` method for class decorator so to not have any weird problems after :) 2. I think it just a a question of preference `the beauty is in the eye of the beholder` right , i prefer to use `functools.partial` in cases like this one and mostly i use `types.*` to test the types of an object, Hope i answer your questions :)

Comment: @mouad: oops, I misunderstood your code. I apologize for the downvote. I will upvote you somewhere else you deserve...

Comment: @ninjagecko: hehehe, no worries :)

Comment: In Python 2.7, the line `super().__init__(wrapped)` raises the exception `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`.

Answer (score 21):

Turns out there's a straightforward solution using `functools.wraps` itself:

```py
import functools

def dec(cls):
    @functools.wraps(cls, updated=())
    class D(cls):
        decorated = 1
    return D


@dec
class C:
    """doc"""

print(f'{C.__name__=} {C.__doc__=} {C.__wrapped__=}')
```

```
$ python3 t.py 
C.__name__='C' C.__doc__='doc' C.__wrapped__=<class '__main__.C'>
```

Note that `updated=()` is needed to prevent an attempt to update the class's `__dict__` (this output is without `updated=()`):

```
$ python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 26, in <module>
    class C:
  File "t.py", line 20, in dec
    class D(cls):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 57, in update_wrapper
    getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr, {}))
AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with my question.  How do I implement `memoized` as a class and provide the wrapping functionality?

Comment: @NeilG if it makes you feel better, this at least answered *my* question, which mapped to the title of the OP question but not the specific memoize example.

Comment: This solved my problem of searching an equivalent of `functools.wraps` for clases

Answer (score 5):

I needed something that would wrap both classes and functions and wrote this:

```
def wrap_is_timeout(base):
    '''Adds `.is_timeout=True` attribute to objects returned by `base()`.

    When `base` is class, it returns a subclass with same name and adds read-only property.
    Otherwise, it returns a function that sets `.is_timeout` attribute on result of `base()` call.

    Wrappers make best effort to be transparent.
    '''
    if inspect.isclass(base):
        class wrapped(base):
            is_timeout = property(lambda _: True)

        for k in functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS:
            v = getattr(base, k, _MISSING)
            if v is not _MISSING:
                try:
                    setattr(wrapped, k, v)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        return wrapped

    @functools.wraps(base)
    def fun(*args, **kwargs):
        ex = base(*args, **kwargs)
        ex.is_timeout = True
        return ex
    return fun
```

Comment: Side note, I invite everybody to use this `.is_timeout=True` idiom to mark your timeout caused errors and accept this API from other packages.

Answer (score 1):

All we really need to do is modify the behavior of the decorator so that it is "hygienic", i.e. it is attribute-preserving.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def hygienic(decorator):
    def new_decorator(original):
        wrapped = decorator(original)
        wrapped.__name__ = original.__name__
        wrapped.__doc__ = original.__doc__
        wrapped.__module__ = original.__module__
        return wrapped
    return new_decorator
```

This is ALL you need. In general. It doesn't preserve the signature, but if you really want that you can use a library to do that. I also went ahead and rewrote the memoization code so that it works on keyword arguments as well. Also there was a bug where failure to convert it to a hashable tuple would make it not work in 100% of cases.

Demo of rewritten `memoized` decorator with `@hygienic` modifying its behavior. `memoized` is now a function that wraps the original class, though you can (like the other answer) write a wrapping class instead, or even better, something which detects if it's a class and if so wraps the `__init__` method.

```
@hygienic
class memoized:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            key = (tuple(args), frozenset(kw.items()))
            if not key in self.cache:
                self.cache[key] = self.func(*args,**kw)
            return self.cache[key]
        except TypeError:
            # uncacheable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
            # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
            return self.func(*args,**kw)
```

In action:

```
@memoized
def f(a, b=5, *args, keyword=10):
    """Intact docstring!"""
    print('f was called!')
    return {'a':a, 'b':b, 'args':args, 'keyword':10}

x=f(0)  
#OUTPUT: f was called!
print(x)
#OUTPUT: {'a': 0, 'b': 5, 'keyword': 10, 'args': ()}                 

y=f(0)
#NO OUTPUT - MEANS MEMOIZATION IS WORKING
print(y)
#OUTPUT: {'a': 0, 'b': 5, 'keyword': 10, 'args': ()}          

print(f.__name__)
#OUTPUT: 'f'
print(f.__doc__)
#OUTPUT: 'Intact docstring!'
```

Comment: The @hygienic does not work for code where the wrapped decorator class has a class attribute. Mouad's solution works though. The problem reported is: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'level'` when trying to do `decoratorclassname.level += 1` inside the `__call__`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using inheritance:

```
import functools
import types

class CallableClassDecorator:
    """Base class that extracts attributes and assigns them to self.

    By default the extracted attributes are:
         ['__doc__', '__name__', '__module__'].
    """

    def __init__(self, wrapped, assigned=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS):
        for attr in assigned:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
        super().__init__()

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return types.MethodType(self.__call__, obj)
```

And, usage:

```
class memoized(CallableClassDecorator):
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """
    def __init__(self, function):
        super().__init__(function)
        self.function = function
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            return self.cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            value = self.function(*args)
            self.cache[args] = value
            return value
        except TypeError:
            # uncacheable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
            # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
            return self.function(*args)
```

Comment: The reason you shouldn't use this is because, as you show, you have to call the `__init__` method of the parent classes (not necessarily just `super()`; you should google for `method resolution order python`).

Comment: @ninjagecko: Isn't it up to the super class to call the `__init__` method of the other parent classes?

Comment: It somewhat of an open question, as far as I know, I may be wrong though. http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385759/should-init-call-the-parent-classs-init does not seem to indicate any consensus.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Yes, I've read the first article.  What I've been doing is to always call super().__init__ from every class no matter what.  This way I can count on all `__init__` methods being called as long as everyone I inherit from does this.  Unfortunately, I've discovered that PyQt classes don't do this.  I really thought that this was how co-operative inheritance had to work, but from what you're saying it sounds like I might be the only one!