# Difference between class decorator and Inheriting class

Tags: c#, inheritance, decorator

I was learning about NUnit and found we use class decorators like `[TestMethod]` before every test function.

Then i learnt about decorators at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208933/10362396) link. According to this answer

> When You add decorator in C# it is like adding a property to the **class/method**. There will be an attribute attached to it.

I just want to ask if I want to use property to be used in whole class (not talking about one method) then why don't I choose inheritance over class decorator

What is the difference ...

Comment: They are called *Attributes*. They are metadata and can be applied to a class, method, property etc. Inheritance and attributes are like oranges and apples; cannot be compared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorators versus inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406446/decorators-versus-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful because the [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208618/what-does-it-mean-to-decorate-a-class-or-parameter) is using the word *Decorator* to refer to 2 entirely different concepts. The question in that link is asking this question:

> What does it mean to Decorate a class or parameter?
>
> What's the purpose and when would I do this?

Some answers, answer the question correctly specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208726/4228458) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31209671/4228458). Both of these are talking about the [Decorator Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern).

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208933/4228458) answer is talking about something entirely different. Although *decorator* can be used to mean *Attributes* (the ones with square brackets in C#) but that SO thread is using it to mean both the *Decorator Pattern* and *Attributes*.

---

**Attributes**

Attributes are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

---

**Decorator Pattern**

Decorator Pattern pattern is explained [here](https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern).

---

**Decorator Pattern vs Inheritance**

There is a good comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842978/decorator-pattern-versus-sub-classing).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is there could be exponentially many sub classes if you use inheritance over decorator.

The main point of using attribute decorator like that is for cross-cutting concern, you can reuse the same decorator across many classes & methods (reusable)

In your case, it's entirely different. `[TestMethod]` is used as a "marker" instead of as a decorator to let the framework know which method is a test method. I don't see any relationship to inheritance in this case.

You could also use interfaces as "marker", but it's not as flexible as using attributes in this case.

Comment: Can you please explain ? I didn't get what are you saying

Comment: @TeraByte: Let's say if you have 3 decorators & 5 classes that you can apply to, you have to write only 8 classes. But if you use inheritance, you need to have 3x5 (15 classes) and the number could be exponential if you have more classes and functionality.

Comment: @TeraByte: but in your example of `[TestMethod]`, it's more like a "marker" attribute instead of class decorator. I don't see any relationship to inheritance in that case