# How to preserve a docstring of a decorated class for sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, docstring

I have a decorator that has a nested definition of the wrapping class. 
Wrapper maintains as the attribute the original class that it wraps.
Toy example looks like this:

```py
def decorator(cls):
    class Wrapper(object):
        original = cls

        def __init__(self):
            self.__doc__ = self.original.__doc__
            self.__name__ = self.original.__name__

        def do_something_with_cls(cls):
            pass

    return Wrapper
```

Now I want to decorate the `Foo` class with this decorator in the other module and generate sphinx documentation for the `Foo` class before it has been decorated. It looks like this:

```py
from .bar import decorator


@decorator
class Foo(object):
    """The docstring I want to preserve."""
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I was trying to achieve this with use of the `autoclass` functionality but it didn't work out. What i wanted to do was to create a class instance and take its docstring:

```
.. autoclass:: package.baz.Foo()
   :members:
```

but it returned this in the html documentation of the `package.baz.Foo` class: `alias of package.bar.decorator.<locals>.Wrapper`

I want to achieve that when I am documenting the `baz` module I am able to generate a documentation of the Foo class before its decoration. Is it possible?

EDIT:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394511/python-functools-wraps-equivalent-for-classes) looks like a similar problem but here what I would like to achieve is to pass to the `Wrapper` instance the docstring that Sphinx will see and generate a documentation basing on the original `Foo` docstring or I will be able to call a `Wrapper.original` and make a documentation of this, but the following didn't work out:

```
.. autoclass package.baz.Foo.original
   :members:
```

Comment: Use [**`wraps`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python functools.wraps equivalent for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394511/python-functools-wraps-equivalent-for-classes)

Comment: Both solutions will not work out because:

1. wraps are not compatible for the class passed as the parameter
2. I am here decorating the whole class with the function that defines the Wrapper class inside. In the attached problem there is the class that decorates the function.

Or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `@wraps` is not working you can update `__doc__` manually.

Do something like:

```
def decorator(cls):
    class Wrapper(object):
        original = cls

        def __init__(self):
            self.__doc__ = self.original.__doc__
            self.__name__ = self.original.__name__

        def do_something_with_cls(cls):
            pass

    Wrapper.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
    return Wrapper


@decorator
class Foo(object):
    """The docstring I want to preserve."""
    def __init__(self):
        pass


print(Foo.__doc__)
```

> 'The docstring I want to preserve.'

Comment: You are my hero! I don't know why I didn't figure out that I need to specify this outside of the class definition and did the same but in the __init__ phase... Thank you very much, works perfectly!