# How to decorate a class method with a callable class?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, callable

I want functions in a class to store their returned values in some data structure. For this purpose I want to use a decorator:

```py
results = []
instances = []

class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @decorator
    def f1(self, a, b):
        return self.data + a + b

    @decorator
    def f2(self, a):
        return self.data + a + 1

x = A(1)
x.f1(1, 2)
x.f2(3)

print(results)
```

The question is, how to implement this decorator.

The main idea is the following:

```py
class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        res = self.func(*args)
        results.append(res)
        instances.append(args[0])

def decorator(func):
    return Wrapper(func)
```

But then I am getting an error message:

```
TypeError: f1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

This question is similar to what other people asked ([How to decorate a method inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367514/how-to-decorate-a-method-inside-a-class), [Python functools.wraps equivalent for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394511/python-functools-wraps-equivalent-for-classes)), but it is not clear where to put `@functools.wraps` or to call `@functools.update_wrapped()` in my case.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on whether want class-specific or instance-specific storage. For example, if you have 2 instances of `A`, let's call them `x` and `y`, do you want these to write to the same list or not?

Comment: My question is formulated the way that all instances write to the same list. Actually, I am more interested to register class instances as well. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're asking for.

```py
In [8]: from functools import wraps 
   ...: results = [] 
   ...: instances = [] 
   ...:  
   ...: class A: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, data): 
   ...:         self.data = data 
   ...:  
   ...:     def decorator(f): 
   ...:         @wraps(f) 
   ...:         def inner(*args, **kwargs): 
   ...:             retval = f(*args, **kwargs) 
   ...:             results.append(retval) 
   ...:             return retval  
   ...:         return inner 
   ...:         
   ...:  
   ...:     @decorator 
   ...:     def f1(self, a, b): 
   ...:         return self.data + a + b 
   ...:  
   ...:     @decorator 
   ...:     def f2(self, a): 
   ...:         return self.data + a + 1 
   ...:                                                                                         

In [9]: a = A(3)                                                                                

In [10]: a.f1(2,3)                                                                              
Out[10]: 8

In [11]: results                                                                                
Out[11]: [8]
```

Decorator does not have to be in the class, but it's handy when you need to access the class instance itself. You can take it out without any code change.

```py
In [8]: from functools import wraps 
   ...: results = [] 
   ...: instances = [] 

   ...: def decorator(f): 
   ...:         @wraps(f) 
   ...:         def inner(*args, **kwargs): 
   ...:             retval = f(*args, **kwargs) 
   ...:             results.append(retval) 
   ...:             return retval  
   ...:         return inner 
   ...:  
   ...: class A: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, data): 
   ...:         self.data = data 
   ...:  
   ...:         
   ...:  
   ...:     @decorator 
   ...:     def f1(self, a, b): 
   ...:         return self.data + a + b 
   ...:  
   ...:     @decorator 
   ...:     def f2(self, a): 
   ...:         return self.data + a + 1 
   ...:                                                                                         

In [9]: a = A(3)                                                                                

In [10]: a.f1(2,3)                                                                              
Out[10]: 8

In [11]: results                                                                                
Out[11]: [8]
```

will work the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have `Wrapper` in class outside, you can implement `__get__` method ([descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html)):

```
from functools import partial

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        bound_f = partial(self.__call__, obj)
        return bound_f

    def __call__(self, other_self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self.func(other_self, *args, **kwargs)
        results.append(res)
        return res

def decorator(func):
    return Wrapper(func)

results = []

class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @decorator
    def f1(self, a, b):
        return self.data + a + b

    @decorator
    def f2(self, a):
        return self.data + a + 1

x = A(1)
x.f1(1, 2)
x.f2(3)

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[4, 5]
```