# python decorator on class: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am using decorators on top of classes to register components. Here is my code

```
import functools
registry = {}

def register(name=None):
    """A decorator for registering modules
    :param name: (optional) name for component
    """
    def _wrap_func(func):
        registry[name or func.__name__] = func

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _wrap_args(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return _wrap_args
    return _wrap_func

class Base:

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

@register(name="module1")
class Module1(Base):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Module1, self).__init__(arg=arg)
        # super().__init__(arg=arg)

@register(name="module2")
class Module2(Base):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Module2, self).__init__(arg=arg)
```

So far good. The `registry` and `register` works as expected

```
print(registry)
# {'module1': <class '__main__.Module1'>, 'module2': <class '__main__.Module2'>}
```

But, calling the constructor on decorated classes throws an error.

```
module1 = Module1(arg='some1')
print(module1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp.py", line xx, in <module>
    module1 = Module1(arg='some1')
  File "/tmp.py", line xx, in _wrap_args
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp.py", line xx, in __init__
    super(Module1, self).__init__(arg=arg)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function
```

I assumed `functools.wraps` took care of hiding the decorator, but here it is not.
If I change `super(Module1, self).__init__(arg=arg)` to `super().__init__(arg=arg)`, it works!
Is this an expected behavior with decorators or is there something wrong with my definition of `registry()` function?

---

EDIT: I lately discovered that inheritance is broken

```
@register(name="module3")
class Module3(Module1):
    pass
```

leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line xx, in <module>
    class Module3(Module1):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I understand that the decorated class becomes a function, but how to fix this? Its just not so obvious from documentation.

1. I have referred to [PEP-3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) and they say
   *For a detailed examination of decorators, please refer to [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318)*
   Not a single example for class decorators with arguments!
2. Most useful documentation I've found is [*Primer on decorators*](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#decorating-classes)
   They left out class decorators **with arguments**.

Comment: maybe that's because classes are not functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python functools.wraps equivalent for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394511/python-functools-wraps-equivalent-for-classes)

Comment: does that mean we shouldn't use decorators on (derived) classes?

Comment: The problem you have atm is that once decorated, `Module1` is seen to be a function, (ie your `_wrap_func()` from your decorator. So just use `super().` when you can.

Comment: `register` is written as a function decorator. Why are you applying it to classes? Or if it's supposed to be a class decorator, why does it return functions?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica because the docs / PEP said "_The semantics and design goals of class decorators are the same as for function decorators; the only difference is that you're decorating a class instead of a function._"  And they didn't give an example for class decorator. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/#semantics  Didn't know what else to do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied `@dataclass` implementation and found the correct way. [Unlike what's said in docs and guides elsewhere](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/#semantics), Class decorator implementation is slightly different than function decorator -- we don't need to receive args and call it.

Here is the one that works:

```
def register(cls=None, name=None):
    """
    A decorator for registering modules
    :param name: (optional) name for this component
    """
    def _wrap_cls(cls):
        registry[name or cls.__name__] = cls
        return cls
    if cls is None:
        return _wrap_cls
    else:
        return _wrap_cls(cls)
```

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer without commenting why!  
with `cls=None` argument, it handles both `@register` and `@register()` usages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that, you actually return a function from your decorator not a class anymore. Why don't you just register the class then return the class itself ?

```
registry = {}

def register(name=None):
    def inner(cls):
        registry[name or cls.__name__] = cls
        return cls

    return inner


class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg


@register(name="file1")
class Module1(Base):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Module1, self).__init__(arg=arg)


@register()
class Module2(Base):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        print('init called from Module2')
        super(Module2, self).__init__(arg=arg)


print(registry)
print(registry['Module2'](10))
```

Everything works fine, output:

```
{'file1': <class '__main__.Module1'>, 'Module2': <class '__main__.Module2'>}
init called from Module2
<__main__.Module2 object at 0x000001B83B0B7FD0>
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense to create class registry using decorators since they aren't inherited. you can save all that typing by adding the code to a base metaclass init method. edit: i mean __new__ method