# python basic explanation needed

Tags: python

Can someone please explain me the following code
TickGenerator inherit from object and methods of Observer, why do we need both observer.init?

```
class TickGenerator(Observer):
    def __init__(self):
        Observer.__init__(self)
        self.price = 1000
```

Comment: the canonical way to call the parent constructor is using the `super()` builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call Observer.**init** as below:

```
class TickGenerator(Observer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 1000
```

It means you override the TickGenerator.**init** method and Observer.**init** will not be called automaticlly.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you came from a language where the parent class constructor is automatically called.

In Python, if you override the `__init__` method, the parent class constructor will not be called unless you call it explicitly.

Until Python 3, it used to be called as:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TickGenerator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The new `[super()][1]` syntax ([PEP-3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/)) is just:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `Observer.__init__(self)` isn't it a calling to the super class constructor ?

Comment: I guess the OP question is why he has to call `Observer.__init__(self)` at all, and it makes sense if he is versed in a computer language where the parent constructor call is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

Because programmer needs **Observer** class `__init__` to be done in addition to 
what is being done in the current class's (**TickGenerator**) `__init__`.

[This Stackoverflow answer will help you understand more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385759/should-init-call-the-parent-classs-init/1385836#1385836)