# Python convention: should I normally call the super class' __init__?

Tags: python, class, convention

I read the highest rated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385759/should-init-call-the-parent-classs-init?lq=1), and it says we should call the super class' `__init__` if we need to, and we don't have to. But my question is more about convention.

Should I *normally*, as a general rule, always call the superclass' `__init__` in my class' `__init__`, regardless of whether or not I currently 'need' the functionality in that method?

Comment: Please don't vote to close this question. I can see that it would be worth closing for other languages. Python, however, strongly emphasizes coding conventions and what is "Pythonic," including the idea that there should generally be one correct way to write things; that's why I think this is a valid question, essentially asking whether it is Pythonic to include a call to the superclass's __init__ by default or not.

Comment: @Ghopper21 Thanks for supporting, please vote to reopen.

Comment: If it were a convention you probably wouldn't have to search so hard to get an answer. Seems to be an opinion based issue: sometimes it's **convenient** to call `super().__init__`, other times you can do the member initialization by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some classes need their `__init__` method to be called in order to work.  They use their `__init__` method sets attributes that will be needed.

Example:

```
class one ():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.number = 20
    def show_number(self):
        return self.number
```

If you inherit from the above class, you will need to call its `__init__` method in order to define the attribute `number`.  If the `__init__` method is not called you could get an error when you try to call the method `show_number`.

As for the syntax, if nothing happens in the `__init__` method of the inherited class you don't need to call it.  If you think not calling the `__init__` method would confuse others, you can always explain your reasoning with comments.  It does not do any harm to call it even if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has some downvotes because the downvoters disagree with me on the focus, and perhaps on what "convention" means. I think we mostly agree on the actual practice when it comes to writing code.

---

**No.** You should not *normally*, as a general rule, always call the superclass's `__init__` in your class's `__init__`, *regardless of whether or not you currently "need" the functionality in that method*.

But please note that my emphasis is on that last phrase, starting with "regardless", and **that** is what my "no" answer is meant to address. You shouldn't be throwing something into your Python code "just because someone told you to" or "just because that seems to be what most people are doing".

You should include something if it is needed, and not include something if it is not.

It is very often the case, some would argue that it is *normally* the case, that you *do* want to call the superclass's `__init__` method in your subclass's `__init__` method. *I do this myself most of the time.*

But why?

Crucially, it is **not** because of some "convention". I do it because my subclass *normally* needs the same initialization as the superclass, plus a bit of extra customization. Note that the extra customization is the whole reason for overriding `__init__` in the first place. If the initialization of your subclass is meant to be identical to that of the superclass, then you shouldn't be defining your own `__init__` at all.

---

It's not a convention in Python to code something you don't need. Some people have *their own* conventions to include unnecessary things; perhaps in the name of "defensive programming" or because they are used to a different language in which more boilerplate is required.

Where Python's conventions come in is when you have a choice between multiple ways to express *something useful*. It's true that Python does not emphasize brevity above all else. But that doesn't mean it emphasizes verbosity either. So let me add this, in case it's not clear:

You should *normally*, as a general rule, always avoid unnecessary boilerplate code. (And not just in Python.)

*[For those who think the phrase "normally always" is awkward or nonsensical: I completely agree, but I was trying to emphasize my point by repeating the asker's own choice of words.]*

Comment: "could even conceivably be a convention ...". It is convention to call the base class's [new if you override it](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__). Yet you don't need to. So I think it is very easy for someone to conceive the same is true for init.

Comment: It's not boilerplate if the semantics require it. I feel like this answer is conflating a few concepts: don't override `__init__` if all you do is call the parent's `__init__`. "Normally" doesn't mean "always". I'd say the cases where you need to override `__init__` but don't need to (or shouldn't) call upstream `__init__` as well are rare.

Comment: @chepner - I agree 100% that it's not boilerplate if the semantics require it. In fact, **that was the ENTIRE POINT of my answer**. I guess I interpreted the question too literally; i.e. is it a *convention*? To me, a convention is something that has no *intrinsic* reason for doing it, other than to go with the flow. 4-space indents and using `self` (instead of `this` or whatever) are examples of conventions. These are very strong conventions in Python, but there is no intrinsic reason they have to (or even should) be that way. I've edited the answer to hopefully make my intent more clear.

Comment: @spinkus - I don't believe that it is convention to use `__new__` if you don't need it. The documentation you linked to doesn't suggest you should either, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I phrased that about as poorly as I could have. Boilerplate, of course, is necessary code that you have to write yourself rather than have it generated for you. The invariant in Python, you have to invoke an overriden method explicitly if you want it to be called; in the case of `__init__`, there are clear cut times when (for your code to function properly), the parent class's `__init__` must be called. *Not* calling `__init__` means you are inheriting only from `object`, and you know (or are dictating) that your class will not be used in a cooperative inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @chepner - I was about to delete my comment and redo it, but you've already "replied" so I'll just amend it with this addendum: The reason I felt this question was *specifically* about convention is that the asker says exactly that. It is **the whole reason** for differentiating this question from the linked one. Notice that this question was even closed as a duplicate and only reopened due to support for the idea that a question about *convention* is useful, apart from "best practice", logical justification, etc. (which are covered by the linked-to question).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** As a general rule you *should* call the superclass's `__init__` from a subclass's `__init__`  method. This is not a Python convention, it is what OO best practice suggests you should do (given the language you happen to be using, leaves this decision up to you):

The superclass doesn't know about the subclass, but the subclass is expected to know about the semantics of the superclass it inherits from. Ultimately it is up to the subclass to maintain a consistent behavior of a true [sub-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) (which unfortunately, the Python language does little to help the programmer with). You, as the subclass implementer get to decide whether or not you need to call the superclass `__init__`, just like you get to decide whether you do/don't need/want to call the superclass's implementation of any method you override. However, initialization of an object tends to be a pretty important step in the life-cycle of many objects. Until the object has been initialized one can argue the object is not truly an instance of the given class. It is an implied and important post-condition in ~all sane OO languages that when you instantiate an object certain things have happened and we can *depend* on those things having happened, initialization (or "construction" in other languages) being the central thing - whether it involves complex parameter validation and computed value generation, or is just a null op. So if you don't call super's initializer you better know exactly what your in for.

Another argument for calling super's `__init__` as a general rule is, if you didn't write the superclass, or your not tightly controlling the version, the implementation of `__init__` may change in future (does adding something to `__init__` call for a major version bump? I'm not sure but I bet a lot of folks wouldn't bump the major version number for that, even if technically they should). So if you do call super's `__init__` your code is less likely to break with updates to the superclass implementation.

---

**Update:** Should have read the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385759/should-init-call-the-parent-classs-init?lq=1) before answering this question. Most of the answers over there echo the general sentiment here - perhaps not in the same terms or as strongly in favor of calling `__init__()` as a general rule as I am. But I'll leave this answer for others that fall here.

Comment: I agree. You can write *valid* Python code without calling the upstream `__init__`, but your object may not be initialized properly if you don't.

Comment: The asker de-accepted my answer, so you may want to adjust your statement. (Unless you think the now-accepted answer is *also* misleading at best.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Statement adjusted.