# Why would a python class that inherits 'object' call 'super' in its __init__ method?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-requests, super

I was poking around at the source of the `requests` module, and noticed [this code:](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py)

```
class Response(object):
    """The :class:`Response <Response>` object, which contains a
    server's response to an HTTP request.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Response, self).__init__()
        ... more init method...
```

My understanding of `super()` suggests this call wouldn't do anything at all. I've found [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753640/inheritance-and-overriding-init-in-python) about [superclass calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/python-invoke-super-constructor), but all work from subclasses of other classes, not `object` itself. The [python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super), too, don't mention this construction.

It occurred to me this might simply be a mistake, and if you `git blame` that file to the [commit that introduced that line](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/ab27027aa8916e6e199bbb35083beb5d6339f6aa/requests/models.py), you'll see that at the time of authorship, `Response` was a subclass of `BaseResponse`. Is the line just a holdover from a class refactoring, or does it this super() call do anything at all?

Comment: afaik, it's unnecessary here, but harmless, and a standard thing to do for subclasses of any kind, since invoking superclass constructors isn't automatic - this might even have been auto-inserted by a RAD tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Corley Brigman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280166/why-would-a-python-class-that-inherits-object-call-super-in-its-init-met#comment28547816_19280166), it's unnecessary but harmless.

For some background, the `BaseResponse` class was added during Kenneth's sprint on Requests 1.0. The 1.0 code change introduced [transport adapters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters), which make it possible to define specific behaviour for some HTTP endpoints (or indeed [non-HTTP endpoints](https://github.com/Lukasa/requests-ftp)). An important part of the Transport Adapter interface is the [`HTTPAdapter.build_response()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.build_response) method, which takes the returned raw response from `HTTPAdapter.send()` and builds a Requests `Response` object from it.

It is clear that Kenneth saw potential utility in having some form of abstract base class for `Response`s, which would allow transport adapters to return `Response`s with very different behaviours to the standard HTTP `Response` object. For this reason, the refactor into an ABC with the bulk of the logic in the subclass seemed to make sense.

Later in the refactor this got yanked out again as unnecessary complexity. The reality is that people wanting to define specialised `Response` objects can simply subclass `Response`, rather than having an ABC that does nothing much. This makes the mainline use case (vanilla Requests) much cleaner in the code, and takes away almost no utility.

When the `BaseRequest` class got pulled out, this line got overlooked, but since it causes no problems there's never been need to remove it.

Comment: For anyone reading over this answer, "ABC" = "Abstract Base Class". I stumbled over that one the first read through.

Answer (score 4):

This code might actually do something if *Response* becomes part of a multiple inheritance tree.  The next class in the "MRO" list could be something other than *object*!  In that case, the call to *super* could be very much **necessary**.

For example,

```
class NewerClass(A, Response):
    def __init__(self):
        ... do stuff ...
        super(NewerClass, self).__init__()
```

From that class definition and without knowing what the hierarchy of *A* is, you can not determine what the next class that `super(Response, self).__init__()` calls will be.  It might be *object* or it might be a base class of *A*.

I think one problem is that the name *super* causes confusion.  It does not act like Smalltalk's *super* variable unless you only use single inheritance, and it does not return a "super class" object.  Instead what it is doing is figuring out the "next" class to be used according to MRO order.

Classic articles on the subject are:
[Python's Super Considered Super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and [Python's Super Considered Harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).

Comment: Interesting point. Yet another reason to avoid multiple inheritance, unless you really really ... really know what you are doing and need it.

Comment: Very often multiple inheritance is used only to add a "mixin" or "interface" class.  That type of multiclassing is a lot simpler to work with.

Answer (score 0):

darinbob is right.
When talking about single inheritance, it is unnecessary, but with multiple inheritance, things are different:

```
class WithSuper:
    def __init__(self):
        print('With super')
        super().__init__()

class NoSuper:
    def __init__(self):
        print('No super')

class TestOne(WithSuper, NoSuper):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Test 1')
        super().__init__()

class TestTwo(NoSuper, WithSuper):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Test 2')
        super().__init__()


one = TestOne()
print(TestOne.__mro__)

print('\n' * 2)

two = TestTwo()
print(TestTwo.__mro__)
```

Run the code above with python3, you'll see the difference.

```
Test 1
With super
No super
(<class '__main__.TestOne'>, <class '__main__.WithSuper'>, <class '__main__.NoSuper'>, <class 'object'>)



Test 2
No super
(<class '__main__.TestTwo'>, <class '__main__.NoSuper'>, <class '__main__.WithSuper'>, <class 'object'>)
```