# twython inheritance variable

Tags: python, class, twython

I'm trying to extend a class, TwythonStreamer in twython. Followed:
[[Inheritance and Overriding __init__ in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753640/inheritance-and-overriding-init-in-python][1]). Redefining the on_success method which works fine. My problem is adding a count variable and initializing it to zero. I get the error "TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)" because I'm messing up the **init**().

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer

C_KEY = "my_key"
C_SECRET = ""
A_TOKEN = ""
A_SECRET = ""

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyStreamer, self).__init__()
        self.count = 0
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            self.count += 1
            print("found it.", self.count)

stream = MyStreamer(C_KEY, C_SECRET, A_TOKEN, A_SECRET)

stream.statuses.filter(track="Primary")
```

Comment: Your `__init__` needs a parameter for everything you're passing (plus self).  You haven't added any parameters to its signature.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by adding after I created stream:

```
stream.count = 0
```

and deleting my **init**

Now in the object I can use self.count. 
This works but is at best inelegant.